# Is dot product always of different vector quantities?

Tags: vectors

I know that work is dot product of **Force** and **Displacement**.

But in definition: $$A \cdot B = |A||B| \cos(x)$$

I want to know whether the two vectors $A$ and $B$ representing the same physical quantities, (i.e., suppose $\text{velocity} \cdot \text{velocity}$), makes any sense.

If not, then in practical applications do they always represent two different physical quantities as in case of **Work**?

In real life, does the multiplication of vectors make any sense or we have defined dot product just for the sake of calculation?

I googled a lot but couldn't get my doubts cleared.

Comment: Kinetic energy $\; =\frac12 m\;( \vec{v}\cdot \vec{v})$. If you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 3):

Vectors have an orientation and a magnitude (for speed, that is how fast you are going and in which direction you are going). The dot product has a very clear geometrical interpretation. If you take any two vectors, the dot product is telling you how "aligned" those two vectors are: it is 0 if the vectors are perpendicular, it is a positive number if they are aligned and the bigger this number is the more the vectors are aligned.

Imagine you have two vectors $a$ and $b$ on a plane with the same origin. You project vector $a$ on $b$ (i.e. you draw the "amount" of $a$ which is along $b$). That amount is $|b|cos(\theta)$, $\theta$ being the angles between the two vectors. Then you multiply this number by the magnitued of $|a|$ and you get $|a||b|cos(\theta)$ and that is the dot product.

So basically, the dot product is the product *not* of the vectors but of the *components* of the vectors along a direction.
In the case of work, you want to know how much of a given force $F$ is aligned with a given displacement $x$. That is way you get the term $cos(\theta)$: you want to know "how much" force is along the displacement. If you push in $x$ but move only in $y$ then the dot product is 0 because there is no component of $F$ along $y$!

The two vectors however can be anything: if you want to know the angle between two cars having two different velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ you can use
$$v_1 \cdot v_2 = |v_1||v_2|cos(\theta)$$ where $||$ denotes the magnitudue.
In the special case in which $v_1=v_2$ you get (because $cos(\theta)=0$)
$$v_1 \cdot v_1 = |v_1|^2$$ i.e. the squared magnitude of the vector: very useful to compute it fast ;)

Also, if you have a direction in space such as $x=(1, 0, 0)$ (indicating the $x-$direction in 3D space, then
$$v_1 \cdot x$$ is going to tell you how much of $v_1$ is oriented along $x$.

Of course, only some dot products have phyisical sense, but nothing is stopping you from using it on any two vectors in the same space: if you want to know how much of the force is oriented in the direction of the acceleration (for instance) you can use the dot product - but that does not mean that that is a relevant quantity in general! You can still multiply apples and oranges, that does not mean the result is interesting.

Notice that dot product is *not* a multiplication in the strict sense because the result of the dot product of tw vectors is a number, not a vector. However it shares with multiplication several similarities, such as commutativity ($a\cdot b= b\cdot a$), $v\cdot 0=0$ where $0$ is an "empty" vector etc.

Another way of multiplying vectors is the *cross* product, whose result is a vector but which is not commutative.

Answer (score 0):

They can both be the same; they can both be velocities for example in which case you can use it to find the angle between them.

> In real life does multiplication of vector makes any sense or we have
> defined dot product just for the sake of calculation?

Everything we define, we define for the sake of calculation. Everything is made up and abstract. Its link to the real world is called an interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Dot product is defined with this equation

$$\vec a\cdot \vec b=|a|\,|b| \,\cos(\varphi)\tag 1$$

where $\vec a,~\vec b~$ are arbitrary vectors not necessary the same  units
the result is scalar this mean that you can chose the components of the vectors in arbitrary  coordinate system.

**Case I x-y system**

$$\vec a=  a \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\varphi) \\
   \sin(\varphi)\\
\end{bmatrix}~,\vec b= b \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Eq. (1)

$$\vec a\cdot \vec b=a_x\,b_x+a_y\,b_y=a\,b\,\cos(\varphi)$$

**Case II x'-y' system**

$$\vec b=  b \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\varphi) \\
   -\sin(\varphi)\\
\end{bmatrix}~,\vec a= a \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Eq. (1)

$$\vec a\cdot \vec b=a_x\,b_x+a_y\,b_y=a\,b\,\cos(\varphi)$$

thus the result of case I and II are the same  .

according to Eq. (1), if $~\varphi=\frac \pi2~$ thus  $\vec a\perp \vec b~,~\vec a\cdot \vec b=0~$

if $~\varphi=0~$ $~\vec a~$ thus
$\vec a \parallel \vec b,~\vec a\cdot \vec b=|a|\,|b|~$

if $~\vec a=\vec b~$ then $~\vec a\cdot \vec a=a_x^2+a_y^2$